# how to generate the tensorflow doc for offline viewing

Tags: python, tensorflow, documentation

How do you generate the [tensorflow docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs) on windows (or wsl).

I have tried to run `setup.py build` and `setup.py install` but all that did was build and install the module.